# Did the Crooked Man intend to kill his victim?

Tags: raising-dion

The Crooked Man killed

> Mark, Dion's father.

He *claims* that he simply couldn't help it, and that he just saw him there while he was trying to kill Charlotte, and that he was being driven by a hunger for powers that overcame his rational thoughts. However, we've seen that his personality is fairly self-serving, and there's a distinct possibility that he is not being honest with Nicole, or even perhaps with himself.

He also has three pretty compelling reasons for wanting to kill Mark:

> We've seen that he's romantically interested in Nicole and jealous of Mark, and we have also seen that he wants to be first in Dion's life. In addition, he seems to think that taking the energy and souls of people with powers will help him stay healthy longer.

So did the Crooked Man kill Mark for any of the aforementioned reasons? Or was it, as he said, simply him being overcome by his limited senses and hunger while trying to kill Charlotte?

Comment: *Raising Dion*?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Appears to be yes, I've changed the tag. Adamant, if this isn't about _Raising Dion_ could you edit this to clear it up?

Comment: I naively assumed that the Spanish title was a direct translation of the English title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Probably

A few pieces of evidence in the second season undermine Pat's arguments about his powers driving him to kill Mark, leaving his personal motivations as the more plausible factor.

First, Pat claims that he was driven by an uncontrollable hunger for the energy of powered people, as a consequence of the influence of the Crooked Man powers. However, we see another person, Brayden, who is possessed and influenced by the Crooked Man energy; even though the entity or energy played upon his worst impulses and influenced him to do terrible things, it notably did *not* cause him to try to consume the energy of other powered people. Since near the end of the season, with his disease cured, Pat nonetheless injects himself with a serum that he correctly believes will restore some measure of his powers, it seems that this hunger for superpowered energy is something that comes largely from *him*, even if the Crooked Man powers exaggerate it, which belies his claims of being overwhelmed by an external force. He then later willing accepts the Crooked Man entity back into himself, even calling it his "old friend."
As Nicole says to him, he is the Crooked Man, with or without superpowers.

> You're the Crooked Man, Pat. You're the one with the darkness inside
> of you. You're the one that wanted to be Mark, right up until the
> moment where you killed him. With or without powers, that is never
> going to change.
>
> *Raising Dion*,"Sankofa" (S02E02)

Second, we see that despite his innocent demeanor, Pat really is quite villainous. As mentioned previously, after a brief stint where he half-heartedly tries to play the hero and help search for a solution to Nicole's infection, Pat injects himself with the serum in the desperate hope of recovering *any* power. *After* doing so, but before rejoining with the Crooked Man, he uses his telekinetic abilities to turn the supercooling guns of two guards on each other, very likely killing or severely injuring them. It was completely unnecessary for him to do so in order to escape: he simply did it because he wanted to. This establishes that even when not under the influence of the Crooked Man, he is perfectly willing to use powers to satisfy his petty urges.

These actions fairly firmly establish the villainous motivations hiding behind his evasion of any responsibility.

Finally, we also see Pat open up with Nicole about his motivations in a rare moment of honesty:

> PAT: Everybody else got good stuff in Iceland. I only got the bad. It
> was killing me. The only thing that made me feel better was...
> consuming Powered people. And their good energy quieted the bad. At...
> You know, at least for a little while.
>
> NICOLE: Yeah, you thought killing Dion could cure you.
>
> PAT: Dion's special.
> More powerful than any of them, but... But also, he was...
>
> NICOLE:
> What?
>
> PAT: An... An answer to me. My opposite.
>
> NICOLE: How? Why?
>
> PAT: I... I can only tell you how it felt. Dion was born from you and
> from the great Mark Warren, and the two of you were so in love, and I
> was unhappy and jealous. I felt I never got what I deserved, which was
> everything. And Dion just was pure goodness, and I... I wanted that.
>
> *Raising Dion*, "With Friends Like These" (S02E04)

While admitting that he was partly motivated by the desire to allay the harm that his powers were doing to him, he also admitted that he would have killed Dion in part because of his jealousy of Mark. It is hard not to think that if that is the case, he certainly would have killed Mark for the same reason.